# Serde Conditional Deserialization for Binary Formats (Versioning)

Tags: rust, serde

I'm trying to deserialize data in a simple non-human readable and non-self describing format to Rust structs. I've implemented a custom `Deserializer` for this format and it works great when I'm deserializing the data into a struct like this for example:

```rust
#[derive(Serialize, Deserialize)]
pub struct Position {
    x: f32,
    z: f32,
    y: f32,
}
```

However, let's say this `Position` struct had a new field added (could have been removed too) in a new version:

```rust
#[derive(Serialize, Deserialize)]
pub struct Position {
    x: f32,
    z: f32,
    y: f32,
    is_visible: bool, // This field was added in a new version
}
```

But I still need to support both data from both versions of `Position`. The version of the data (known at runtime) can be given to the `Deserializer` but how can the `Deserializer` know the version of a field (known at compile time)?

I've looked at `#[serde(deserialize_with)]` but it didn't work because I cannot get the needed version information.

I 've also looked at implementing `Deserialize` manually for `Position` and I can receive the versions of the fields of `Position` by implementing something like `Position::get_version(field_name: &str)`.

However, I cannot figure how to get the version of the data currently being deserialized because `Deserialize::deserialize` only has a trait bound `Deserializer<'de>` and I cannot make that bound stricter by adding another bound (so it doesn't know about my custom `Deserializer`).

At this point, I'm thinking about giving the version data of each field when instantiating the `Deserializer` but I'm not sure if that will work or if there is a better way to go.

Comment: This might be relevant: https://outcrawl.com/event-versioning-rust

Comment: quickest way would be to wrap the newly added attributtes in an `Option`

Comment: @Netwave I'm not sure this could work because the format is non-self describing and I don't know how to tell the `Deserializer` there is no value there (there might be other fields to deserialize afterwards)

Answer (score 2):

### Multiple structs implementing a shared trait

If you have several different versions with several different types of struct, and you want a more robust way of handling different variants, it might be a better idea to write structs for each possible format. You can then define and implement a trait for shared behavior.

```rust
trait Position {
    fn x(&self) -> f32;
    fn y(&self) -> f32;
    fn z(&self) -> f32;
    fn version_number(&self) -> usize;
}

struct PositionV0 {
    x: f32,
    y: f32,
    z: f32
}

impl Position for PositionV0 { 
    fn x(&self) -> f32 {
        self.x
    }

    // You get the idea for the fn y, fn z implementations

    fn version_number(&self) -> usize {
        0
    }
}


struct PositionV1 {
    x: f32,
    y: f32,
    z: f32,
    is_visible: bool,
}

impl Position for PositionV1 { 
    fn x(&self) -> f32 {
        self.x
    }

    // You get the idea for the fn y, fn z implementations

    fn version_number(&self) -> usize {
        1
    }
}
```

Answer (score 2):

[Carson's](https://stackoverflow.com/a/72185951/18615570) answer is great when you do not have a lot of versions but for me I am working with data structures that range over 20 different versions.

I went with a solution that while I don't think is the most idiomatic, is capable of handling an arbitrary number of versions.

In short:

- we implement a `Version` trait which gives the necessary version info to the `Deserializer`
- `Deserializer` has `VersionedSeqAccess` (implements `serde::de::SeqAccess`)  that sets a flag
- When flag is set, we put `None` for that field and immediately unset the flag

The idea is to implement the following trait for the struct:

```
pub trait Version {
    /// We must specify the name of the struct so that any of the fields that 
    /// are structs won't confuse the Deserializer
    fn name() -> &'static str;
    fn version() -> VersionInfo;
}

#[derive(Debug, Clone)]
pub enum VersionInfo {
    /// Present in all versions
    All,

    /// Present in this version
    Version([u16; 4]),

    /// Represent Versions of structs
    Struct(&'static [VersionInfo]),

    // we can add other ways of expressing the version like a version range for ex.
}
```

Here is how it will be implemented for the example struct `Position`. This type of manual deriving is error prone so this can be improved with a derive macro (see end):

```
struct Position {
    x: f32,
    z: f32,
    y: f32,
    is_visible: Option<bool>, // With this solution versioned field must be wrapped in Option
}

impl Version for Position {
        fn version() -> VersionInfo {
            VersionInfo::Struct(&[
                VersionInfo::All,
                VersionInfo::All,
                VersionInfo::All,
                VersionInfo::Version([1, 13, 0, 0]),
            ])
        }
        fn name() -> &'static str {
            "Position"
        }
}
```

Now, the deserializer will be instansiated with the version of the data format we are currently parsing:

```
pub struct Deserializer<'de> {
    input: &'de [u8],

    /// The version the `Deserializer` expect the data format to be
    de_version: [u16; 4],

    /// Versions of each field. (only used when deserialzing to a struct)
    version_info: VersionInfo,

    /// Whether to skip deserialzing current item. This flag is set by `VersionedSeqAccess`.
    /// When set, the current item is deserialized to `None`
    skip: bool,

    /// Name of struct we are deserialzing into. We use this to make sure we call the correct
    /// visitor for children of this struct who are also structs
    name: &'static str,
}

pub fn from_slice<'a, T>(input: &'a [u8], de_version: [u16; 4]) -> Result<T, Error>
where
    T: Deserialize<'a> + Version,
{
    let mut deserializer = Deserializer::from_slice(input, de_version, T::version(), T::name());
    let t = T::deserialize(&mut deserializer)?;

    Ok(t)
}
```

Now that the deserializer has the all the information it needs, this is how we define `deserialize_struct`:

```
fn deserialize_struct<V>(
        self, name: &'static str, fields: &'static [&'static str], visitor: V,
    ) -> Result<V::Value, Self::Error>
    where
        V: Visitor<'de>,
    {
        if name == self.name {
            if let VersionInfo::Struct(version_info) = self.version_info {
                assert!(version_info.len() == fields.len()); // Make sure the caller implemented version info somewhat correctly. I use a derive macro to implement version so this is not a problem
                visitor.visit_seq(VersionedSeqAccess::new(self, fields.len(), &version_info))
            } else {
                panic!("Struct must always have version info of `Struct` variant")
            }
        } else {
            // This is for children structs of the main struct. We do not support versioning for those
            visitor.visit_seq(SequenceAccess::new(self, fields.len()))
        }
    }
```

Here is how `serde::de::SeqAccess` will be implemented for `VersionedSeqAccess`:

```
struct VersionedSeqAccess<'a, 'de: 'a> {
    de:           &'a mut Deserializer<'de>,
    version_info: &'static [VersionInfo],
    len:          usize,
    curr:         usize,
}

impl<'de, 'a> SeqAccess<'de> for VersionedSeqAccess<'a, 'de> {
    type Error = Error;

    fn next_element_seed<T>(&mut self, seed: T) -> Result<Option<T::Value>, Error>
    where
        T: DeserializeSeed<'de>,
    {
        if self.curr == self.len {
            // We iterated through all fields
            Ok(None)
        } else {
            // Get version of the current field
            let version = &self.version_info[self.curr as usize];
            self.de.version_info = version.clone();

            // Set the flag if the version does not match
            if !is_correct_version(&self.de.de_version, &version) {
                self.de.skip = true;
            }

            self.curr += 1;
            seed.deserialize(&mut *self.de).map(Some)
        }
    }
}
```

The final part of the puzzle is inside `deserialize_option`. If we are at a field not found in current data format the skip flag will be set here and we will produce `None`:

```
fn deserialize_option<V>(self, visitor: V) -> Result<V::Value, Self::Error>
    where
        V: Visitor<'de>,
    {
        if self.skip == true {
            self.skip = false;
            visitor.visit_none()
        } else {
            visitor.visit_some(self)
        }
    }
```

A lengthy solution but it works great for my usecase dealing with a lot of structs with lots of fields from different versions. Please do let me know how I can make this less verbose/better. I also implemented a derive macro (not shown here) for the `Version` trait to be able to do this:

```
#[derive(Debug, Clone, EventPrinter, Version)]
pub struct Position {
    x: f32,
    z: f32,
    y: f32,

    #[version([1, 13, 0, 0])]
    is_visible: Option<bool>,
}
```

With this derive macro, I find that this solution tends to scale well for my usecase.